# Static blocks and variables

Tags: java

Why in the below code is assigning a value to the static variable acceptable but using that same variable is not?

```
class Test
{
static
{
   var=2;  //There is no error in this line
   System.out.println(var); //Why is there an error on this line if no error on the above     line
}
static int var;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [***the usage is not on the left hand side of an assignment***](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/classes.doc.html#287406), as explained below:

*From section 8.3.2.3* of the JLS,  **Restrictions on the use of Fields during Initialization**:

> The declaration of a member needs to appear before it is used only if
>   the member is an instance (respectively static) field of a class or
>   interface C and all of the following conditions hold:
>
> - The usage occurs in an instance (respectively static) variable
>     initializer of C or in an instance (respectively static) initializer
>     of C.
> - The usage is not on the left hand side of an assignment.
> - C is the innermost class or interface enclosing the usage.
>
> A compile-time error occurs if any of the three requirements above are
>   not met.

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question and not posting a workaround.

Comment: But this leaves the question of "why did the JLS authors implement this exact restriction, i.e. how does it make the compiler writer's life easier"? Especially when the assignment **is** ok...

Answer (score 3):

The error you get is `Test.java:6: illegal forward reference`.  Move the `int var` before the static block.

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. But what I wanted to know was the reason for this behavior. Why is there no "Illegal Forward Reference" error when I assign a value to that variable, and there is one when is use that variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
class Test
{
static int var;
static
{
   var=2;  //There is no error in this line
   System.out.println(var); //Why is there an error on this line if no error on the above     line
}
}
```

With the declaration before the use